# Failed to produce diagnostic for expression Error

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
Section("Tip Percentage") {
    Picker("Tip", selection: $tipPercentage) {
        ForEach(tipPercentages, id: \.self) { tip in
        Text("\(tip)", format: .percent)
        }
    }
}.textCase(nil)
```

> Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs)

When I replace `"\(tip)"` with `tip` in this code, I don't get an error, but why?

Below is the full code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var checkAmount = 0.0
    @State private var numberOfPeople = 2
    @State private var tipPercentage = 20
    let tipPercentages = [10, 15, 20, 25, 0]
  
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                Section("Check Amount") {
                    TextField("Amount", value: $checkAmount, format: .currency(code: Locale.current.currency?.identifier ?? "USD"))
                }.textCase(nil)
                
                Section("Number Of People") {
                    Picker("People", selection: $numberOfPeople) {
                        ForEach(2..<100) {
                            Text("\($0) people")
                        }
                    }.pickerStyle(.navigationLink)
                }.textCase(nil)
                
                Section("Tip Percentage") {
                    Picker("Tip", selection: $tipPercentage) {
                        ForEach(tipPercentages, id: \.self) { tip in
                            Text("\(tip)", format: .percent)
                        }
                    }
                }.textCase(nil)
                
                Section("Total Per Person") {
                    Text(checkAmount, format: .currency(code: Locale.current.currency?.identifier ?? "USD"))
                }.textCase(nil)
            }.navigationTitle("WeSplit")
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Comment: You try to format a string as percent but that requires a number which you use in your working example

Comment: AFAIK, the `format: .percent` convert the underlying value (Int) to a string representation.
 So the value in the `Text` need to be an `Int` for the `format: .percent` to do its job,
 as in `Text(tip, format: .percent)`.
 But if you use `Text("\(tip)", format: .percent)` it is a String value, that is not
 compatible with the format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to format a 'FormatInput' into a text, with a 'FormatStyle'. The [Apple developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/init(_:format:)) explicitly states under the discussion: "Use this initializer to create a text view backed by a nonstring value, using a FormatStyle to convert the type to a string representation. Any changes to the value update the string displayed by the text view."

If you now first convert tip into a String with "(tip)", the initializer crashes due to the fact that the FormatInput is a String, which is not expected. So, your second attempt, just using 'tip' is the correct way of using this initializer for the Text structure.

Comment: To be precise, it’s not a crash it’s a compilation error.

Comment: @BraveCat, enjoy coding.